# Sublime & Terminal: ImportError: cannot import name 'request'

Tags: python-3.x

Mac Terminal:

[image]

Sublime Text 3:

[image]

I'm confused why the code could run correctly in Terminal but reporting error in sublime text 3?

Comment: Because Sublime Text's terminal is different from Mac OS's, It's specially made for Sublime text commands, and not the bash ones.

Comment: You can use Sublime REPL to run Python inside Sublime Text, But I still prefer the Terminal. 

https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL